# Can i create virtual touchs on display of phone which based on Android OS?

Tags: android, events

Can i make display of phone feel touched ? Clearly to say, i have one `Point(x,y)` and i want to touch there programatically without using finger. Is there any event to raise and send as parameter touch `Point`?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate touches within your own app, from a test app testing your own app, or for arbitrary third-party apps?

Comment: for arbitrary third-party apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, for obvious security reasons.